# Action delegate in winrt api

Tags: c#, delegates, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

Hi i an developing an app on windows rt.I tried to use Action but it says it is not a valid winrt type.I was not able to find any source about it which could elaborate further.

my code

```
public  void OnNetworkDown(Action NetworkEventHandler )
{
    _OnNetworkDown += NetworkEventHandler;
}
```

> 'Talk.To.Utilities.IO.Socket.TcpSocketAsyncEventArgs.OnNetworkDown(System.Action)'
>   has parameter 'NetworkEventHandler' of type 'System.Action'. 
>   'System.Action' is not a valid Windows Runtime parameter type.

So please direct me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you post some sample code, and the exact compiler error message?

Comment: also update _OnNetworkDown declaration prototype. Seems like + operator is culprit

Comment: How is `_OnNetworkDown` defined?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the manages type Action use a delegate to do this.

```
public delegate void NetworkEventHandler();

public  void AddNetworkDownHandler(NetworkEventHandler handler)   
{      
 _OnNetworkDown += handler;
}
```

But you can also expose the event to the public directly, this will the language projection enable to integrate the even more naturally into other languages like JavaScript.